# Make <div> appear at current scroll position

Tags: php, javascript

Okay, I believe this one will be a hard one... I would search the internet first, but I can't put the question correctly, I only have images and wild guesses as to how it is done. Maybe you will find it interesting too, maybe it is a piece of cake for you... So here we go:

[image]

I believe you (maybe) are familiar with Russia's and Ukraine's social network called VKontake.
It's like Facebook, well, the idea was taken from Facebook.

So, notice the scrollbar and how much space there is. When I click on the underlined  this opens:

[image]

See how the scrollbar changed, and you can only scroll the content of the "wrapper div".
But, the background is still the vk.com/id*myidnumber*, that means no redirection occurred, it only added `?w=wall57371848_7204`

So the question is as follows:

How to "print out" a div that appears on the current scroll position, and is scrollable like on the image.

If you are interested, I can supply you with the code. If it's easy as 1 2 3, please answer :)

Comment: It's not easy as 1 2 3 - basically like this: one parent-div that holds all the scrollable content and changes overflow to hidden and a gets specific height once the modal is open - additionally to that the contents from image1 are placed inside a div that will get a vertical offset when the modal opens - that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want a modal window. There's a great tutorial on how to create one here:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Also the `overflow` element of the DIV tag will define the scrolling capability for the div that is brought up in the modal window itself. That's a CSS thing and is better covered here:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Hope that helps!

Comment: just one question before I read the tutorial: will the modal window appear at the scrolling point?

Comment: If you want the modal window to appear as the user scrolls, or when a certain point is reached, you'll have to do it through Javascript and track the current position. The one thing you have to remember is that when you're talking screen positions, or a "scrolling point," all screen sizes aren't the same. Visibility is based upon resolution, CSS, and amount of content. Track window position or visibility with Javascript, or jQuery.

Comment: the think is, I want the window to appear when the user clicks on a thumbnail of a post. So if he is at the bottom of the page and he clicks on it, it doesn't get him all the way up to the top of the page and then open the modal window.

Comment: The links I provided will accomplish exactly what you're asking for then. Specifically the first one will not change the position of the outer scroll area/page unless you set the inner DIV's positioning. See here for more info on that: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that popup appears to be a child of an element, which has "posision: fixed" style and its width and height are equal to window's.
This fixed element contains another element which has more height (and which contains modal's data), therefore fixed element shows scroll.
Fixed element's scroll overrides body's scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your top level modal div with CSS:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
position: fixed;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

The `position: fixed;` fixes its location against the browser.